# LLVM 10.0.1 - How to set the alignment of the global variable?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to set the alignment of global variable using setAlignment method from llvm::GlobalVariable. However, this member function is reported as "Deprecated" in LLVM 10.0.1. What's the recommended way to set the alignment?

Comment: It is deprecated? I don't see that [in the source code](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/6588592684ff0ec455570e576f8351a36e4ead3a/llvm/lib/IR/Globals.cpp#L117). Generally, when something is deprecated, the commit message will say something about why and what to do instead. Sometimes a kind soul even added a comment, but not very often. The commit log, on the other hand, is reliable, and [git blame](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) is a quick way to find out.

Comment: The following is the warning message which I am getting:
   41 |     gVar->setAlignment(4);
      |                         ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/Support/ErrorHandling.h:17,
    ....
/usr/local/include/llvm/IR/GlobalObject.h:81:34: note: declared here
   81 |   LLVM_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED(void setAlignment(unsigned Align),
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Compiler.h:305:3: note: in definition of macro 'LLVM_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED'
  305 |   decl __attribute__((deprecated))

Comment: The neighbouring line says what to use instead. The function [was removed in April 2020](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/39cfba9e333ce41b67c605173de9bf1575328b8a#diff-d7fc132ada40d25338f8e5e403b9e105724ebf46931e9b103a8f8eca660a6a85) BTW.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was relatively simple. The MayBeAlign solves the Deprecated warning.

```
gvar->setAlignment(**MaybeAlign(16)**);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call [`llvm::GlobalObject::setAlignment`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalObject.html#a49b398b1c83ef4d42c8f7756b443f61f).  GlobalObject is a parent class of GlobalVariable.  For example:

```
llvm::GlobalVariable * var = ...;
var->setAlignment(llvm::Align(4));
```